# node js localhost shal open a file

Tags: node.js

Tutorial: I want to open a file via localhost, but I don't know which path I have to type into the Browser. Is localhost, where my server.js is located? (sorry, I'm new to programming and node)

Tutorial-Code

```
var path = require('path'),
    fs = require('fs');

require('http').createServer(function(req, res) {
  var file = path.normalize(req.url);

  console.log(file);

  path.exists(file, function(exists) {
    if (exists) {
      fs.stat(file, function(err, stat) {
        var rs;

        if (err) { throw err; }
        if (stat.isDirectory()) {
          res.writeHead(403);
          res.end('Forbidden');
        } else {
          rs = fs.createReadStream(file);
          res.writeHead(200);
          rs.pipe(res);
        }
      });
    } else {
      res.writeHead(404);
      res.end('Not found');
    }
  })
}).listen(4000);
```

Comment: It's the CWD most likely.

Comment: Doesn't the console.log statement output what file it's looking for?  Also, the server is listening on port 4000 so you address that app in the browser as http://localhost:4000

Answer (score 2):

`request.url` is normally `/something/like/an/absolute/path` unless you get requests from a HTTP proxy client (which adds `http://...` prefix to `request.url`) or make some custom HTTP requests.

Anyways `path.normalize` only takes care of `..` And  `.`s. 
Your code will let anybody access any file (accessible by the account in which `node` process is running) on your computer.

A better/safer practice is to join `__dirname` with decoded `request.url` and check if resolved path starts with the absolute path (with trailing path separator) of the directory you want to serve static content from:

```
var scriptDir = path.resolve(__dirname + path.sep + "static" + path.sep),
    requestPath = decodeURIComponent(request.url);
requestPath = path.resolve(path.join(__dirname, "static", requestPath));
if (requestPath.indexOf(scriptDir) === 0) {
    // serve the file
} else {
    response.writeHead(403);
    response.end(http.STATUS_CODES[403]);
}
```

Now if you request say, `http://localhost:4000/index.html` it should serve the file located in `/path/to/your/node/app/dir/static/index.html`